# What does the level on a treasure-hunting map mean?

Tags: dragon-quest-9

Whenever I go "treasure-hunting" using maps I've acquired to go to a cave or grotto in Dragon Quest IX, I see a level beside the map I have selected. What purpose exactly does the level of a map serve? Is it extra difficulty or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Higher difficulty.

P.S. Have a look at the DQ-IX wiki for stuff on the special grotto bosses too, the ones which respawn and do all kinds of crazy stuff.